# Navigate through multiple pages in Angular bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a modal with different views. The second view is produced from results that come from the first view. I'm using `ui.bootstrap` module. My problem is that I'm not able to figure out how to implement it. Do you have any suggestion about?

Comment: [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) with `ui-view` or [Angular Router](https://github.com/angular/router) with `ng-view` inside modal body

Comment: I have read somewhere that ui.bootstrap isn't compatible with angularui router

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not very useful to try it like this.
A modal is mainly a "popup" where you can adjust something. Perhaps a detailed view where you can edit table row entries.

But if you really want to have two (or more) modals that depend on each other I would pass the return arguments from one modal to the start arguments of the next modal and open it directly in the controller. Like this:

```js
$scope.openModal1 = function (size) {
  var modalInstance1 = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modal1.html',
    controller: 'modal1Ctrl'
  });
  modalInstance1.result.then(function (modal1Results) {
    var modalInstance2 = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modal2.html',
      controller: 'modal2Ctrl',
      resolve: {
        resultFromModal1: function () {
          return modal1Results;
        }
      }
    });
    modalInstance2.result.then(function (modal2Results) {
      
    }, function (cancel) {
      console.log(cancel + ' Modal2 dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    }
  }, function (cancel) {
    console.log(cancel + ' Modal1 dismissed at: ' + new Date());
  });
};
```

Completely untested so no guarantee that it works "out of the box".

Kind regards,

Stefan